# What does ${ } mean in PHP syntax?

Tags: php, syntax

I have used PHP for a long time, but I just saw something like,

```
${  }
```

To be precise, I saw this in a PHP Mongo page:

```
$m = new Mongo("mongodb://${username}:${password}@host");
```

So, what does `${ }` do? It is quite hard to search with Google or in the PHP documentation for characters like `$`, `{` and `}`.

Comment: Its use is kind of pointless here though, `"mongodb://$username:$password@$host"` would work just as well.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`${ }` (dollar sign curly bracket) is known as [**Simple syntax**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple).

> It provides a way to embed a variable, an array value, or an object
> property in a string with a minimum of effort.
>
> If a dollar sign ($) is encountered, the parser will greedily take as
> many tokens as possible to form a valid variable name. Enclose the
> variable name in curly braces to explicitly specify the end of the
> name.
>
> ```
> <?php
> $juice = "apple";
>
> echo "He drank some $juice juice.".PHP_EOL;
> // Invalid. "s" is a valid character for a variable name, but the variable is $juice.
> echo "He drank some juice made of $juices.";
> // Valid. Explicitly specify the end of the variable name by enclosing it in braces:
> echo "He drank some juice made of ${juice}s.";
> ?>
> ```
>
> The above example will output:
>
> ```
> He drank some apple juice.
> He drank some juice made of .
> He drank some juice made of apples.
> ```

Comment: Great!  And I removed my no-longer-accurate comment. :-)

Answer (score 11):

It's an embedded variable, so it knows where to stop looking for the end of the variable identifier.

`${username}` in a string means `$username` outside of a string. That way, it doesn't think `$u` is the variable identifier.

It's useful in cases like the URL that you gave, because then it doesn't need a space after the identifier.

See the [php.net section](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) about it.

Comment: e.g: `$a = 'blah'; echo "$abc";` will echo nothing since $abc is not set while `$a = 'blah'; echo "${a}bc";` will echo 'blahbc'

Comment: "Complex (curly) syntax" is documented here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex  -- btw, the examples seem to prefer `{$username}` over `${username}` although both work in the simple case.

Comment: I'd avoid using it altogether, just put it into single quotes i.e. this is echo 'Hello, '.$world.', how are you?'; much faster than echo "Hello, {$world}, how are you?";

Comment: See above, posted it too fast.

Comment: What about in situations like the given example of a URL?

Comment: What's the difference here? Just use  this: $m = new Mongo('mongodb://'.$username.':'.$password.'@host');

Comment: @PavelDubinin Readability. If you're optimizing your PHP to that level why not just write C?

Comment: At least in PHP 7 the double-quoted strings is not much slower than single-quoted. Sometimes even faster. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#120160

Comment: @AdrianGünter "if you're optimising your PHP to that level why not just write C" - because - strings; memory leaks; productivity ;)

Comment: @DaveAmphlett yes, but *performance* would never make that list, which is my point. Also, when you sacrifice readability and create more work for yourself by avoiding interpolation you're compromising productivity.

Comment: AdrianGünter I agree @PavelDubinin 's example is awful and his point is actually invalid (in many cases complex syntax is twice as fast as string append - see: https://pastebin.com/TCKk4K6P ) but trying to establish a 'best practice' is important, and can help mitigate some of the speed cost of PHP

Comment: @FrankFarmer The examples for `{$username}` are examples of complex syntax. The examples for `${username}` are examples of simple syntax. You are right that in the simple case they both work!

Answer (score 1):

The [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) provides only a brief description of this usage, and I also have only seen it in a malware sample.

From the documentation:

> In order to use variable variables with arrays, you have to resolve an
> ambiguity problem. That is, if you write $$a[1] then the parser needs
> to know if you meant to use $a[1] as a variable, or if you wanted $$a
> as the variable and then the [1] index from that variable. The syntax
> for resolving this ambiguity is: ${$a[1]} for the first case and
> ${$a}[1] for the second.

Answer (score 1):

`${ }` (dollar sign curly bracket) is known as [**Complex (curly) syntax**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex).

> This isn't called complex because the syntax is complex, but because it allows for the use of complex expressions.

> Any scalar variable, array element or object property with a string representation can be included via this syntax. The expression is written the same way as it would appear outside the string, and then wrapped in { and }. Since { can not be escaped, this syntax will only be recognised when the $ immediately follows the {. Use {$ to get a literal {$. Some examples to make it clear:
>
> ```
> <?php
> $juice = "apple";
>
> echo "He drank some $juice juice.".PHP_EOL;
> // Invalid. "s" is a valid character for a variable name, but the variable is $juice.
> echo "He drank some juice made of $juices.";
> // Invalid
> echo "He drank some juice made of { $juice}s.";
> // Valid. Explicitly specify the end of the variable name by enclosing it in braces:
> echo "He drank some juice made of ${juice}s.";
> ?>
> ```
>
> The above example will output:
>
> ```
> He drank some apple juice.
> He drank some juice made of .
> He drank some juice made of { apple}s.
> He drank some juice made of apples.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I read everywhere about using the `${var_name}` and `{$var_name}` inside of strings in order to delimit variables, but I recently came across this:

```
<?php
$zb8b5 = 419;
$GLOBALS['t91a5'] = Array();
global $t91a5;
$t91a5 = $GLOBALS;
${"\x47\x4c\x4fB\x41\x4c\x53"}['t112f6f9'] = "\x63\x5c\x76\x48\x36\x47\x43\x7b\x35\x7c\x27...";
.
.
.
```

I found the above code when fixing a hacked website.

Note the last line. Turns out it is also possible to use the `${}` syntax to declare variables with odd names.

So you can do (weird) things like:

```
<?php
${"my_var"} = 'asdf';
var_dump($my_var);
${"other_var"}['a_pos'] = 'my value';
var_dump($other_var);
?>
```

Output:

```
string(4) "asdf"
array(1) {
  ["a_pos"]=>
  string(8) "my value"
}
```

It's really a bad practice, of course, unless you're trying to scramble your code, as these guys wanted to do.

[raw-bin hood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2080074/raw-bin-hood) pointed out a reference to the use of `${}` outside strings in the PHP documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: I have also seen this used in almost exact same malware source from: https://github.com/marcocesarato/PHP-Malware-Collection .  In the obfuscators/globals.php file which is what led me here.  Also, I think you forgot the variable name in the second example: var_dump($other_var);

Comment: Fixed the var_dump(). Thanks, raw-bin hood.

Comment: I also found documentation on that usage here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php . The explanation is brief but in the paragraph about half way down.

Comment: Excellent! I added your reference to the answer.