# what does {$variable1}{$variable2} mean?

Tags: php, variables, syntax

I've seen this in a couple of scripts, but got no clue what it means. As already seen in the title of this thread, the syntax is like this: {$variable1}{$variable2}. Is it equivalent to: $variable1.$variable2 ?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Can you give us some more context?

Comment: Duplicate (great) answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571624/php-syntax-question-what-is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is yes, it is the same. A variable contained within those brackets outputs that variable.
Note that you can't do anything like this, sadly:

```
$a = "hello: {$a+1}";
```

or

```
$b = "world: {someFunction($a)}";
```

It's just a quick way of outputting variables so things don't get all complicated.
Try looking at:

```
echo "hello mr {$name}!";
```

vs

```
echo "hello mr ".$name."!";
```

The first is much clearer.

It is much better to put variables in braces because it looks nicer, is clearer to read and also lets you have letters directly after the variable name, e.g:

```
echo "Today is the {$date}st";
```

Comment: Note: they only work with double quotes. so `echo 'some {$variable}';` is not going to work

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is almost always equivalent to using concatenation: `$variable1.$variable2`.

When you embed variables in **double quotes** (not single quotes), [complex (curly) syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex), which uses curly braces, help to distinguish between two following variables, so that there is no confusion in which variable is being referred to.

For instance, suppose that `$test` is equal to `walk`. What if I want to type `walked`?

```
"$tested"
```

refers to an actual variable, `$tested`.

```
"{$test}ed"
```

refers to `$test` and then the phrase `ed`.

Using curly braces is necessary for quoted array indices.

```
echo "Test $array['test]'";
```

doesn't work, but

```
echo "Test {$array['test]'}";
```

does work.

For a more contrived example, suppose that `$a` contains `es` and `$test` contains `foobar`.

You would need to use curly braces in this case:

```
echo "$t{$a}t"; // Returns 'foobar'
```

Usually, it is unnecessary, but sometimes, the interpreter may have some confusion about your variables. Most of the time, it is just for readability purposes.

```
echo "Test {$a}{$b}";
```

looks cleaner than

```
echo 'Test '.$a.$b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's equivalent but it's usefull to clearly identify wich part of a string is the variable name and wich is not.

E.g. :

```
<?php
$var1 = "somevalue1";
$var1is = "somevalue2";
echo "${var1}is nice";  //prints "somevalue1is nice"
echo "$var1is nice"; //prints "somvalue2 nice"
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're already familiar with both `print "hello $user;"` and `print "hello ".$user;`. But if you want to concatenate 2 variables (and you prefer embedding strings like the former example), instead of doing `print "hello ".$user.$something;` you can also do `print "hello {$user}{$something}";`.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be referring to is noted as the [`Complex (curly) syntax` in the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex).