# What does the ${$} construct mean?

Tags: php

I am new to PHP so please i am sorry if this question is a noob. I don't know its name so couldn't find it. I read it in this piece of code. What does it mean?

Line 5: `${$key}`

```
<?php
    $expected = array( 'carModel', 'year', 'bodyStyle' );

    foreach( $expected AS $key ) {
        if ( !empty( $_POST[ $key ] ) ) {
            ${$key} = $_POST[ $key ];
        } else {
            ${$key} = NULL;
        }
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Actually, it's not the `${$` symbol, but a [Variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: and it's not a "wht" it's "What".

Answer (score 3):

This is the same as `$$key` and means a var named `$key`

i.e.

```
$test = "foo";
```

is the same as

```
$a = "test";
$$a = "foo";
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a variable variable. Please read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: I dont understand why people down vote these answers, People should be encouraged to read api's and documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The notation `${$key}` is an alternative writing style to simply `$$key` which is used for [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

One particular case in which you could use that notation is when you do tricks like this:

```
$var = 'foo_x';
$key = 'x';
${'foo_' . $x} = 'hello';

echo $foo_x; // hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Set variable with name $key.

```
$var = NULL;

$name = 'var';

${$name} = TRUE;

var_dump($var); // TRUE
```

As well as:

```
$$name = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a way to use dynmaic variable names. See here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 0):

It allows for the use of complex expressions.

It's called complex (curly) syntax, you can find more information at http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex

Comment: +1. This actually makes an attempt at answering the question :)

Comment: Have a look at this post, has a bit more information in the second answer for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571624/php-syntax-question-what-is

Comment: The biggest part of that particular answer is simply a rip from the manual page ;-)