# In PHP, what does the ${$ } syntax do?

Tags: php, syntax

I ran across this inside a WordPress plugin.

```
$stuff = $wpdb->get_results(" assume valid database query here ");
foreach ($stuff as $cur)
    ${$cur->type}[] = $cur->name;
```

`$stuff` will be an object containing more objects of database rows.  These database rows will have columns `'id'`, `'type'`, and `'name'`.  The `'type'` column will contain one of these three strings: `'file'`, `'url'`, or `'code'`.

It looks like this code snippet will potentially create or add new elements to arrays named `$file`, `$url`, and/or `$code`.  However, I'm not familiar with this use of the ${$ } syntax; I've only seen it inside double quoted strings to avoid parsing problems.

Am I correct in my analysis of this code?  Where can I learn more about this use of the ${$ } syntax?

There is a [question about the ${ } syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5571624/2600278) inside a double-quoted string.  I understand that use, but I'm specifically asking about a second $ character inside the { } braces.

Comment: `{$cur->type}` forces this bit to resolve first, ensuring that `$$cur` isn't the meaning, nor `$cur->type[]`. If you want to know more about the overall approach, look up [variable variables](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=php+variable+variables) - it's a way of writing an expression in which the variable names themselves may change.

Comment: @j08691: That duplicate is actually about something different. Not totally different but not the case here.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: @j08691, I changed the title slightly to look less like a duplicate of that question, which, in my opinion, it is not.

Comment: @Ben - if this question closes as a duplicate of the item j08691 has proposed, ping me and I'll vote to reopen. That mentions the `{}` but not the `$$`.

Comment: @halfer, it was marked as duplicate.  I've got my answer, but if you want to reopen, feel free.  It's not a duplicate of that question.  If anything, it's a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15548950/2600278).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider

```
$foo = 42;
$a = 'foo';
echo $$a; // Prints 42
```

That´s called a variable variable, since the variable´s name is determinated at runtime.
But is $$a[1] the same as ${$a[1]} or the same as {$$a}[1]? The brackets avoid that ambiguity, just like they do when dealing with operator precedence in math.

Answer (score 4):

It's a "variable variable". In this case, it is referring to the array in the variable named whatever is in `$cur->type`.

Personally I hate this, and would much prefer to do this:

```
$someArray[$cur->type][] = $cur->name;
```

Comment: No, variable variable is something else in PHP. That's the thing with `$$` at the beginning: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: @hakre in this case it is variable variable, but the one holding final variable name is in complex form.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller: I don't think so. Property access is more than a single variable that then is the second in variable variable. I'd say this is more like [String Parsing](http://www.php.net/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) then like [Variable Variables](http://php.net/language.variables.variable.php).

Comment: Meh, the example indeed is on the variable variable page, I stand corrected: *"Curly braces may also be used, to clearly delimit the property name. They are most useful when accessing values within a property that contains an array, when the property name is made of mulitple parts, or when the property name contains characters that are not otherwise valid (e.g. from json_decode() or SimpleXML)."* - at least both is correct, manual also on the string page I favored calls it *Complex (curly) syntax*. It's just perhaps there is no central place that documents it.

Answer (score 2):

those curly brackets open a string context evaluating the expression there-in to a string which then is used as variable name.

For example, if you want to write a variable with a name you could never write in normal PHP:

```
echo $;
```

The variable with an empty name. PHP would give you a syntax error. However you can create such variable with the curly brackets:

```
${''} = 'hello';
echo ${''}; # prints "hello"
```

that is a variable with an empty name. This can be helpful if you want to evaluate the variable name first:

```
${$cur->type}[]
| ### 1. ###|
`---- 2. ---´
```

This allows you to clearly say where the array is. In the variable *named* by `$cur->type`.

I probably can not explain it really well, this is a blog post I remember so it's probably worth on the topic:

- [PHP Variable Names: Curly Brace Madness (Jan 2008; by Salathe)](http://cowburn.info/2008/01/12/php-vars-curly-braces/)