# populating dropdown list from mysql - php/html

Tags: php, html, mysql

Trying to populate a dropdown list from my database - connection is ok and in my mind the code I have should work, but currently getting a blank dropdown...
Have looked at [PHP- Fetch from database and store in drop down menu html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701692/php-fetch-from-database-and-store-in-drop-down-menu-html) as well as other tutorials but alas no luck so far!

code is as follows...

```
<?php
//get constants for database
require("database.php");

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection = mysqli_connect ($server, $username, $password);
if (!$connection){  
    die('Not connected : ' . mysqli_error());
}

// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($connection, $database);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysqli_error($connection));
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM route WHERE 1";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);


echo '<select name="list" style="width:400px;">';

while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo "<option value=".$r['alt']."</option>"; 
}

echo '</select>';
?>
```

Comment: Your `option`-tag is broken. Should be something like `echo "<option value='".$r['alt']."'>[Text in dropdown here]</option>"; `

Comment: Yep! Works fine, thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<option>` tag is broken.

Corrected code:

```
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  echo '<option value="'.$r['alt'].'">'.$r['alt'].'</option>'; 
}
```

**Note:** You can use single and double quotes either, but, they should be properly closed.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on this [Select Dropdown Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)

Syntax For Select Dropdown

```
<select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
</select>
```

You have missed a closing of value in option.

```
<?php
//get constants for database
require("database.php");

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection = mysqli_connect ($server, $username, $password);
if (!$connection){  
die('Not connected : ' . mysqli_error());
}

// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($connection, $database);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysqli_error($connection));
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM route WHERE 1";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

//Changes From Here

?>
<select name="list" style="width:400px;">
    <?
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {?>
        <option value="<?echo $r['alt'];?>"><?echo $r['alt'];?></option>
    <?}?>
</select>
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Ok @JayBlanchard. Sorry. Explaining. Editing.

Comment: Why are you including the entire code? Just include the areas you fixed.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
        //get constants for database
        require("database.php");

        // Opens a connection to a MySQL server
        $connection = mysqli_connect ($server, $username, $password);
        if (!$connection){  
            die('Not connected : ' . mysqli_error());
            }

        // Set the active MySQL database
        $db_selected = mysqli_select_db($connection, $database);
        if (!$db_selected) {
            die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysqli_error($connection));
        }

        $query = "SELECT * FROM route WHERE 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);


            echo '<select name="list" style="width:400px;">';

                while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    echo "<option value=".$r['alt'].">".$r['alt']."</option>"; 
                }

            echo '</select>';
            ?>
```

so if your select condition is right/hidden by you then you will have to add a display value between option tag. As per the code you have assigned values in option value tag but not given the values to be displayed. Try the above

Comment: Why are you including the entire code? Just include the areas you fixed.