# What does `${...}` that is not within a string mean in PHP?

Tags: php

What does `${...}` **that is not within a string** mean in PHP? I want to know where the documentation is, too.

```
${"GLOBALS"}["a"]    = "b";
${${"GLOBALS"}["a"]} = "c";
```

#### The context

I'm solving [a wargame challenge on *xcz.kr*](http://xcz.kr/START/prob/prob21.php), and it gave me this obfuscated PHP source code (with some HTML).

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<title>Prob21</title>
</head>
<body style="background-image:url('../images/content-tail.gif');">
<b>Title</b></br>
<i>PHP Obfuscation Crack</i></br></br>
<b>Description</b></br>
<font size="2px">
<a href="prob_files/prob21.html" target="_blank">View source</a></br></br>
<?
${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x67\x61\x73y\x61\x72\x6b\x6e\x64"]="\x62";${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42AL\x53"}["r\x77\x6cii\x69\x71\x66\x76\x66\x70"]="i";function h($a){${"\x47\x4cO\x42\x41L\x53"}["\x70x\x7a\x77\x65\x61h\x72\x75\x71\x6f\x6b"]="\x62";${${"\x47LO\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x70\x78z\x77\x65\x61\x68\x72u\x71\x6f\x6b"]}="";${"GL\x4fB\x41\x4c\x53"}["u\x78\x6fi\x69i\x6b\x61pcv"]="\x62";for(${${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42A\x4c\x53"}["r\x77\x6c\x69\x69i\x71\x66\x76fp"]}=0;${${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42A\x4cS"}["\x72\x77l\x69i\x69\x71\x66\x76\x66\x70"]}<5;${${"G\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x72\x77\x6ci\x69\x69qf\x76\x66\x70"]}++){$ydzorvqk="\x61";$gflrozo="\x62";${"\x47\x4cOB\x41\x4cS"}["\x65\x72p\x78\x7a\x6fz\x64\x65y"]="i";${$gflrozo}=${${"G\x4c\x4f\x42AL\x53"}["\x67\x61sy\x61\x72k\x6e\x64"]}+ord(substr(${$ydzorvqk},${${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42ALS"}["\x65rp\x78\x7a\x6fz\x64e\x79"]},1));}return${${"\x47\x4c\x4fBA\x4cS"}["\x75x\x6fi\x69i\x6b\x61\x70\x63v"]};}$jbojdbertutk="\x4b\x45\x59";$vtefigaylx="mu\x6e";${"G\x4cOB\x41L\x53"}["\x68p\x63eeyx\x74o"]="\x61";$ktjmdjm="a";${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42ALS"}["\x6d\x69mt\x65\x6du\x63\x79\x62\x70c"]="\x6d\x75\x6e";${$jbojdbertutk}="\x43o\x6e\x67\x72a\x74\x75\x6ca\x74\x69\x6f\x6es\x21</\x62r\x3e\x4be\x79\x20i\x73 ?????????????????????";${"GL\x4f\x42\x41\x4cS"}["\x67\x6d\x66i\x66\x62f\x6c"]="\x61";${${"G\x4c\x4f\x42AL\x53"}["\x6d\x69\x6d\x74em\x75c\x79\x62p\x63"]}=@$_GET["\x6b\x65y"];${"GL\x4f\x42A\x4c\x53"}["w\x76d\x63\x78\x73\x64\x73\x71b"]="x";@${$ktjmdjm}=explode("-",${$vtefigaylx});$gfxqkfxurga="\x78";$dlmordkk="\x61";for(${${"\x47\x4c\x4fBA\x4cS"}["w\x76\x64\x63\x78\x73\x64\x73\x71b"]}=0;${${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41LS"}["\x77v\x64\x63\x78s\x64\x73\x71\x62"]}<5;${$gfxqkfxurga}++){if(preg_match("/[^a-\x7a\x41-\x5a\x30-\x39]/",@${${"\x47\x4cOB\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x68pc\x65e\x79\x78\x74\x6f"]}[${${"\x47\x4cO\x42A\x4c\x53"}["\x77vd\x63\x78\x73ds\x71\x62"]}])){exit("\x45rr\x6f\x72!");}}if(is_numeric(substr(${${"\x47LO\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x68p\x63e\x65y\x78to"]}[0],0,2))&&!is_numeric(substr(${${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4cS"}["\x68\x70\x63ee\x79\x78t\x6f"]}[0],4,1))&&h(${${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["gm\x66\x69fbfl"]}[0])>312&&h(${${"\x47L\x4f\x42A\x4cS"}["h\x70\x63e\x65yx\x74\x6f"]}[0])<333&&!is_numeric(substr(${$dlmordkk}[1],0,1))&&is_numeric(substr(${${"\x47\x4c\x4fB\x41LS"}["hpc\x65ey\x78to"]}[1],3,2))){$qcpkjlbgy="\x61";${"G\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x6f\x71\x6f\x74\x6a\x62\x76\x6e"]="\x61";${"G\x4cO\x42ALS"}["bb\x67h\x7a\x6f\x74"]="\x61";if(h(${${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41LS"}["b\x62g\x68z\x6ft"]}[1])>300&&h(${$qcpkjlbgy}[1])<326&&!is_numeric(substr(${${"GL\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["hp\x63\x65\x65yx\x74o"]}[2],0,1))&&is_numeric(substr(${${"\x47LO\x42AL\x53"}["\x68\x70c\x65e\x79xt\x6f"]}[2],1,1))&&h(${${"GLO\x42\x41L\x53"}["o\x71o\x74\x6a\x62\x76n"]}[2])>349&&h(${${"\x47\x4c\x4fB\x41\x4cS"}["h\x70c\x65\x65\x79x\x74o"]}[2])<407){${"\x47L\x4fBA\x4cS"}["\x77\x73ju\x78\x77\x78bz\x6d\x73"]="\x61";${"\x47\x4cOB\x41\x4c\x53"}["o\x66\x76\x6d\x69\x61\x74\x63\x64ko"]="a";$oqhejquzit="a";if(!is_numeric(substr(${${"G\x4c\x4fBA\x4cS"}["\x77\x73\x6au\x78\x77\x78bz\x6d\x73"]}[3],0,2))&&is_numeric(substr(${$oqhejquzit}[3],2,3))&&h(${${"GL\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["o\x66\x76\x6di\x61\x74\x63\x64\x6b\x6f"]}[3])>357&&h(${${"\x47\x4c\x4fBA\x4cS"}["hp\x63\x65ey\x78\x74\x6f"]}[3])<359){${"G\x4c\x4f\x42\x41L\x53"}["\x65rq\x71jp\x63t"]="\x61";${"G\x4c\x4fBAL\x53"}["ok\x67\x6f\x6e\x64\x66\x69\x64\x6b\x79"]="\x61";if(round((h(${${"G\x4c\x4f\x42A\x4c\x53"}["\x68\x70c\x65\x65y\x78t\x6f"]}[0])+h(${${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41L\x53"}["\x6fkg\x6f\x6ed\x66\x69\x64\x6b\x79"]}[1])+h(${${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42AL\x53"}["h\x70c\x65e\x79\x78\x74\x6f"]}[2])+h(${${"\x47L\x4f\x42A\x4cS"}["h\x70\x63e\x65\x79\x78\x74o"]}[3]))/4)==h(${${"\x47L\x4f\x42ALS"}["\x65\x72\x71\x71\x6a\x70ct"]}[4])){$oaqqkxn="\x4b\x45\x59";exit(${$oaqqkxn});}}}}echo"\x57\x72ong\x20\x54.T";
?>
</font>
</body>
</html>
```

And I deobfuscated it with [*UnPHP*, an online PHP deobfuscator](https://www.unphp.net/), and it gave me the code starts with:

```
<?
${"GLOBALS"}["gasyarknd"]   = "b";
${"GLOBALS"}["rwliiiqfvfp"] = "i";
```

I can guess what it means, but I've never seen that syntax before.

#### I've read

- [What does ${ } mean in PHP syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571624/what-does-mean-in-php-syntax) (It seems they're talking about `${...}` within strings, but that's **NOT** what I want to know. I already know what it means.)

Comment: I've just got a downvote. I know this is a stupid question, but I am really not able to find the documentation about it. Maybe because I'm not good at English or lack of searching ability?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann It seems they're talking about `${...}` **within strings**; if isn't, please let me know. I would appreciate it.

Comment: yeah, seen that, removed my comment cause of that. my bad. but out of curiosity: in what context did you see that syntax? i've never seen it before

Comment: It means the same thing inside and outside strings.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Added the context.

Comment: @JJJ Then, is `($"GLOBALS")["a"] = 1;` valid in PHP?

Comment: No. Why would it be?

Comment: @JJJ Okay, I understood. It seems it works like Object.assign(window, {[...]: ...}); in JavaScript; it evaluates the expression inside ${...} and takes it as the name of the variable to access. Thank you so much. Do you know where the documentation for it is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is covered in the documentation under the topic ["Variable variables"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

> In order to use variable variables with arrays, you have to resolve an ambiguity problem. That is, if you write `$$a[1]` then the parser needs to know if you meant to use `$a[1]` as a variable, or if you wanted `$$a` as the variable and then the `[1]` index from that variable. The syntax for resolving this ambiguity is: `${$a[1]}` for the first case and `${$a}[1]` for the second.

So basically, you can use `${<expr>}` to access a variable of the dynamic name `<expr>`, where `<expr>` can be any expression that returns a string. Alternatively, you could write:

```
$foo = "GLOBALS";
${$foo}["gasyarknd"] = "b";

// equivalent to:
$GLOBALS["gasyarknd"] = "b";
```

Of course, in the context of your question, `${"GLOBALS"}` is not actually a variable variable, since `"GLOBALS"` is a static string, and not a variable. Semantically, it means the exact same thing as `$GLOBALS`.

---

For more information, you can also have a look at the respective rule from [PHP's grammar](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_language_parser.y):

```
simple_variable:
        T_VARIABLE          { $$ = $1; }
    |   '$' '{' expr '}'    { $$ = $3; }
    |   '$' simple_variable { $$ = zend_ast_create(ZEND_AST_VAR, $2); }
;
```

The second part of the rule, `'$' '{' expr '}'`, covers just this: `${`, followed by any expression, followed by `}` is a completely valid way to access a variable in PHP. The third part of the rule covers "regular" variable variables, like `$$foo`.